# Whitelist local server in google chrome

Tags: server, local, whitelist

I have a local server setup using ubuntu/docker. I have Calibre-Web setup. Whenever I download anything from the server I get a "insecure download block".

I'm looking to whitelist it on specifically google chrome.

The server is called "Tron" on 192.168.4.206